# Align a div to center

Tags: html, css, margin, center-align

I want to float a `div` to center. Is it possible? `text-align: center` is not working in IE.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

There is no float to center per se. If you want to center a block element inside another do this:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">Stuff to center</div>
</div>
```

with:

```
#outer { width: 600px; }
#inner { width: 250px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Now that won't make the text wrap around it (like it would with a float left or right) but like I said: there is no float center.

Comment: For those frustrated after doing this and it still isn't working, put 'display:inline-block;' in your "#outer" arguments

Comment: I know this is an old question. Now we can simply use <div align="center">

Comment: Also, to override float set it to none

Answer (score 25):

This has always worked for me.

Provided you set a fixed width for your DIV, and the proper DOCTYPE, try this

```
div {        
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works great with a DIV that isn't fixed width as well, just add `display: table;`

Answer (score 12):

#### The usual technique for this is `margin:auto`

However, old IE doesn't grok this so one usually adds `text-align: center` to an outer containing element. You wouldn't think that would work but the same IE's that ignore `auto` also incorrectly apply the text align center to block level inner elements so things work out.

And this doesn't actually do a real float.

Comment: text align center not working in IE ... Ross cab give me any other ans

Comment: Note that 'old IE' means IE 5.x and earlier, which most people don't concern themselves with these days.

Comment: Don't you even have to do `text-align: center` on IE6?

Comment: Only in Quirks Mode (and you should not be using quirks mode except under truly exceptional circumstances)

Answer (score 6):

floating divs to center "works" with the combination of display:inline-block and text-align:center.

Try changing width of the outer div by resizing the window of this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qB48w/)

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="block">one</div>
    <div class="block">two</div>
    <div class="block">three</div>
    <div class="block">four</div>
    <div class="block">five</div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.outer {
    text-align:center;
    width: 50%;
    background-color:lightgray;
}

.block {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid lime;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: .2rem;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Following solution worked for me.

```
  .algncenterdiv {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

One of my websites involves a div whose size is variable and you won't know it ahead of time. it is an outer div with 2 nested divs, the outer div is the same width as the first nested div, which is the content, and the second nested div right below the content is the caption, which must be centered. Because the width is not known, I use jQuery to adjust accordingly.

so my html is this

```
<div id='outer-container'>
<div id='inner-container'></div>
<div id='captions'></div>
</div>
```

and then I center the captions in jQuery like this

```
captionWidth=$("#captions").css("width");
outerWidth=$("#outer-container").css("width");
marginIndent=(outerWidth-captionWidth)/2;
$("#captions").css("margin","0px "+marginIndent+"px");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use "spacer" divs to surround the div you want to center. Works best with a fluid design. Be sure to give the spacers height, or else they will not work.

```
<style>
div.row{width=100%;}
dvi.row div{float=left;}
#content{width=80%;}
div.spacer{width=10%; height=10px;}
</style>

<div class="row">
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="content">...</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me..

```
div.className {
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to float dynamically created divs in an outer div.. I can have 1 or 2 divs.. if there was 1 div then it should float in center and if there were 2 divs then float side by side.. i hope its clear :)

Answer (score 1):

this could help you..:D

```css
div#outer {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  float:left;
  position:fixed;
  border:solid 5px red;
}
div#inner {
  border:solid 5px green;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <center>
    <div id="inner">Stuff to center</div>
  </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't.

You can either have content bubble up to the right of an element (`float: left`) or to the left of an element (`float: right`), there is no provision for having content bubble up on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="outer" style="z-index:10000;width:99%;height:200px;margin-top:300px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;float:left;position:absolute;opacity:0.9;">

<div id="inner" style="opacity:1;background-color:White;width:300px;height:200px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">Inner</div></div>
```

Float the div in the background to the max width, set a div inside that that's not transparent and center it using margin auto.

Answer (score 0):

this works nicely

```
width:40%; // the width of the content div
right:0;
margin-right:30%; // 1/2 the remaining space
```

This resizes nicely with adaptive layouts also..

CSS example would be:

```
.centered-div {
   position:fixed;
   background-color:#fff;
   text-align:center;
   width:40%;
   right:0;
   margin-right:30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

I included an unordered list on my page twice. 
One div class="menu" id="vertical" the other to be centered was div class="menu" id="horizontal". Since the list was floated left, I needed an inner div to center it. See below.

```
<div class=menu id="horizontal">
<div class="fix">
  Centered stuff
</div>
</div>

.menu#horizontal { display: block;  float: left; margin: 0px; padding: 0 10px; position: relative; left: 50%; }
#fix { float: right; position: relative; left: -50%; margin: 0px auto; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it helped me: wrap the div in  tags, the problem is that it will center the content of the div also (if not coded otherwise). Hope that helps :)