# Use Margin Auto and Center to center Float Left Div

Tags: css

I know this question had been asked many times.

[Align a div to center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740587/float-a-div-to-center)

However, I follow their suggestion :

```
<center>
  <div style="margin : auto; text-align: center">
    <a href="#" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">Menu Item 1</a>
    <a href="#" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">Menu Item 2</a>
    <a href="#" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">Menu Item 3</a>
  </div>
</center>
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [google.com](http://sites.google.com/site/yanchengcheok/Home/a.png))</sub>

By using "Center" and "Margin Auto", "Text Align Center" ... I still unable to center the menu item.

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated. Use `<div>` instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use inline-block instead of float left.

```
<center>
  <div style="margin : auto; text-align: center">
    <a href="#" style="display: -moz-inline-box; display: inline-block; left; margin-right: 10px;">Menu Item 1</a>
    <a href="#" style="display: -moz-inline-box; display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px;">Menu Item 2</a>
    <a href="#" style="display: -moz-inline-box; display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px;">Menu Item 3</a>
  </div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not use an unordered list? After all, you are creating a list of links.

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
</ul>

li {
  display: inline;
}

ul {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I need to use div. The example I gave is just a simplified version.

Answer (score 3):

Your code works fine, but the `div` is 100% wide by default so you won't notice any centering.

Either give the `div` a width (fixed in pixels or relative in percent) or, if you just want to center the menu *items*, give the div a `text-align` setting:

```
<div style="margin : auto; text-align: center">
```

Comment: @Yan remove the `float: left` from your links and it will work.

Comment: I need to use float left too.

Comment: @Yan Elements with a `float: left` can't be centered. You could only center the `div` then by giving it a width.

Answer (score 0):

Work for me (not used float, only text-align): 
      http://jsfiddle.net/vnAvk/20/

```
<div class="a">
    <p>A div Hello</p>
    <p class="center">
        <a class="b">B Div hello</a>
        <a class="c">C Div Hello</a>
        <a class="d">D div Hello</a>
        <a class="e">E div Hello</a>
    </p>
</div>

div.a { border: 1px solid red;} 
p.center { text-align: center; }

a.b { border: 2px solid blue; } 
a.c { border: 2px solid green; } 
a.d { border: 2px solid black; } 
a.e { border: 2px solid yellow; }
```