# Internet Explorer CSS - Center Div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, doctype

I recently made a website but I'm having a really big problem with Internet Explorer. The CSS seems to do strange things in IE. 
Rather than copying hundreds of lines of CSS here is a link to a page of the site: http://www.appwheal.com/app/ios/angry-birds-space
All the content should be displayed in the middle of the screen. Instead with IE it is stuck to the left.

I'm using

```
margin-left: auto;

margin-right: auto;
```

This is supported by IE, right.

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Float a div to center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740587/float-a-div-to-center)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to declare a `DOCTYPE`, or Internet Explorer defaults to Quirks mode (IE5 compatibility).  Go into Internet Explorer, hit F12 to bring up Developer tools, and notice that it shows "Quirks" mode under Document Mode.  Quirks doesn't support any of the known div centering methods around, and declaring the [DOCTYPE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) is the easiest (and recommended) way to fix it.

To set your page for XHTML 1.0 Transitional (which is the most common), use

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

To declare the page is HTML5 compatible, use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The `DOCTYPE` line needs to be the first line in the html file, appearing BEFORE the opening `<html>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, I feel silly that I forgot this. At least I didn't have to change loads of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You must also set

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

#yourDiv {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: The DOCTYPE isn't set; IE is rendering the page in Quirks mode.

Comment: Yeah, if you change the document mode in the developer tools to IE7, it works perfectly without changing the CSS, so setting text-align: center in the body isn't necessary

Comment: OK, i'll give you that. but generally speaking, it is considered only half of the solution to set margin: 0 auto; there are plenty of tutorials that say for reliability's sake, you should include the other part (align center for body, align left for your wrapper)

Answer (score 1):

Set margin and width :

```
#yourDiv {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the old school text-align:center
And try top:50%; left:50%; and offset suitable negative pixels