# Making <ul><li> list align center

Tags: css

I am applying dynamic classes "float-left", "float-right" and "float-center" to the Lists to position them properly where I want, but for centering as there is no float:center; I tried with margins, inline-block; text-align:center.. but nothing works.. please check this fiddle

```
 ul.tabs .center {
   margin:0 auto;
   text-align:center;
   overflow:hidden;
 }

 .float-center li{
   display:inline-block;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/443E2/

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740587/float-a-div-to-center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
.float-center {
    text-align: center;
}
.tabs.float-center li {
    display: inline-block;
    float; none;
    margin-left: -4px;  /* Fix for white spaces between li while using inline-block */
}
.tabs.float-center li:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
}
```

See the update <kbd>[jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/443E2/4/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Check this fork - http://jsfiddle.net/GzS7X/

I changed this to centre the content of the `<li>`:

```
.tab_content {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: its the same, the content is center but the LI themselves are left aligned.. I want the tab buttons to be aligned centered..