# Float left and text-align center

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a mini-register bar on the left side of the site, and on the middle to create some data page.
So I used `float:left` for the mini-register bar and `text-align:center` for the body.
I read this [Align a div to center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740587/float-a-div-to-center) and now tried instead of `text-align` property, use `margin: 0 auto` for whole div.
But now the body sticks to the left mini-register bar and isn't placed on the center.

**Mini register bar**

```
<div id="LoginOrRegister">
        <form action="#" method="post" style="margin-top:30px;">
Username: <input id="text" type="text" required="required">
        Password: <input type="password" required="required"></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In"> <strong>Or</strong> <a href="#"><button>Register</button></a>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Body data**

```
        <div style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <p>
        <h1><u>some data</u></h1>
  </p>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#LoginOrRegister  {
  float:left;
    border: 4px solid #0279ec; 
    padding:5px; 
    width: 260px;  
    height:140px;
    }
button, input {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

**A demo**
http://jsbin.com/yofeluna/1

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `margin`, give your `div` this instead:

```
position:absolute;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
```

`position:absolute` will make sure it's the center of the screen, and not the center of whatever space is left on the right of the form.

[***DEMO***](http://jsbin.com/yofeluna/5/)

Comment: After the body there's a footer, and he goes up either though he isn't included inside of the `div`. why is this happening?

Comment: Because once you set something to `absolute`, it's taken out of the flow of the layout. You'll need to account for this if you are to use `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 1):

I added width and text-align property to your body text container: http://jsbin.com/yofeluna/4

```
<div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center">
```

Comment: No need for the margin in this case :)

Comment: True, but if he wanted to change the width to a set dimension, then it would still work.