# Cannot Float Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-float

I am just a beginner in coding with HTML/CSS, and I am having trouble trying to float a specific div. Every time a type: "float:center" it will not work. Any ideas? (The div bellow will have "*" around it.)

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>Java Source-Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Java-Source-CSS.css">
    </head>

    <body>

            ***<div id="buttons">***
                <a href="Java-Source-Home.html">Home</a>
                <a href="">Videos</a>
                <a href="">Downloads</a>
                <a href="">Help</a>
                <a href="">Contact</a>

                <div id="header">
                    <h1>Java Source_</h1>
                </div>
            </div>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Java-Source-JS.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS Code

```
body {
        background-color: white;
    }

    #header {
        float: right;
        background-color: orange;
        font-family: Courier;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-right: 30px;
        margin-top: 40px;
        height: 70px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px; 


    }

    #buttons {
        background-color: grey;
        height: 80px;
        width: 1260px;
        float: center;
        clear: both;

    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        font-family: Courier;
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 5px;
        background-color: orange;
        margin-left: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        clear:both;
    }

    a:hover {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: red;
    }
```

Keep in mind I'm just a beginner with HTML/CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I center float elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767971/how-do-i-center-float-elements)

Comment: There is no such function float:center, use text-align:center or margin:0px auto instead

Comment: Next time please only include relevant code. Don't give html that's not related to the question. That way you won't have to use asterisks to point the section you want out

Answer (score 2):

`float: center` doesn't exist. Only possible properties are `right`, `left`, `none`, and `inherit`.
 If you use `right` or `left`, the element will be taken from the normal flow of the web page and placed at either right or left side of its parent element. Text and inline elements will wrap around the floated element.

 To know more about `float` you can have a read on this page: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

To center your block-level element horizonally you can use `margin: 0 auto`. The element needs to have a width speciefied, in your case it's `1260px`. What `auto` will do, is that the remaining space right and left of the element is split evenly between margin-right and margin-left.

And here's a little example: http://jsfiddle.net/4yw3M/ 
You can see, the yellow div is centered horizontally with `margin: 0 auto`.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: No, it's a legit answer. It answers the question right?

Comment: You can also `float` `none` and `inherit` ;D

Comment: @Zove It *is* an answer, but incomplete. Editing it to include more information is also an option.

Comment: No more information is needed, except perhaps a link to MDN or another related SO post

Comment: @bjb568 Thanks for editing. What further information is missing?

Comment: 1) Float will remove element from normal flow, auto margin won't. 2) An example use of auto margin. 3) A fiddle or code pen would also be nice.

Comment: Nice. It's great to see people willing to (and capable of) improve themselves. +1

Answer (score 0):

There is no such CSS rule as `float: center`.

You need to use other methods to center such as `text-align: center` or `margin-right: auto`.

See this post for help: [Align a div to center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740587/float-a-div-to-center)

Comment: But even if I were to use something like text-align: center, it will not center it.

Comment: Take a look at the linked post